# How can I get row and column id of an Excel sheet in my winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

In my Winform application, I am reading data from an Excel sheet.

If data (i.e. string) is invalid, I have to send its location in the Excel file to user (for ex. A12)

Can any one help me, how can I do this?

Comment: It would help to explain how you are reading the excel file in the first place. If you want a 3rd party library then [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is pretty easy to use

Comment: also considering NewAmbition's answer I would say this question needs some more effort from the OP or be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using interop and have the row and column of the cell, you can use the following:

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)CurrentWorksheetObject.Cells[row, col];
   string cellAddress = range.get_AddressLocal(false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

You can then pass that string to the user.

Comment: Perhaps make it a little more clear as to what `get_AddressLocal` does and what it returns?